# How to avoid circle observe in MVVM

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm

I'm iOS developer and use ReactiveCocoa to implement MVVM in Objective C.

I have a UITextField with property `text` (view). View model property `nameString` (view model) observe `text` (view) change. Model property `name` (model) observe `nameString` (view model)

In inverse way, `nameString` (view model) observe `name` (model). UITextField `text` (view) observe `nameString` (view model)

Below image show how new text set when user type to text view. The new text will be update to text view again:

[image]

So, when user type a new string. The text field will be set this text again.
How can I prevent it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Call `distinctUntilChanged` whenever you observe:
`RAC(self, nameString) = [RACObserve(model, name) distinctUntilChanged];`